# If $|a|= \infty$, then $<a>$ is infinite subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of:

> Let $G$ be group and $a \in G$.
>   If $|a|= \infty$, then $<a>$ is infinite subgroup.

The proof I have here goes like:

> Let $|a|=\infty$. Then $a^i ≠ a^j$ for all $i≠j$, because otherwise
>   $|a|≤ |i-j|.$ 
> Which proves the statement.

---

I don't understand why must $a^i ≠ a^j$ and how this relates to the order of the element (or the subgroup).

Comment: If $a^i = a^j$, then $a^{\lvert i-j\rvert} = e$.

Comment: "how this relates to the order of the group" You probably mean: how this relates to the order of the subgroup <a>... But then you know that <a> contains every a^i and that the elements a^i are all distinct, hence...

Comment: Silently modifying the question is one thing, to address explicitely the comments made about it would be more productive.

Comment: @DanielFischer That would pass as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that for some $i\not= j$, you have $a^{i}=a^{j}$. Assume without loss of generality that $i<j$. Then, multiplying $a^{-i}$ to both sides gives $e=a^{j-i}$. Since $j-i>0$, this gives that $|a|\leq j-i$, contradicting that $|a|=\infty$. Therefore, it must be that for all $i\not= j$, $a^{i}\not= a^{j}$. Hence, $<a>=\{a^{i}\mid i\geq 0\}$ is an infinite set.

Answer (score -2):

It is known that if $G$ is finite cyclic group and has order $n$ then the subgroup $H$ order will be number divisible by $n$, so let the subgroup $H$ order be $r$ then $r.x=n$ for positive $x$, now in your task assume that $H$ is finite then $n$=infinity must divide $r$ which is not true, so the subgroup $H$ is finite.